# RSpec: undefined local variable or method `activate_authlogic'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

My `_spec` file includes the code below, but my test fails with:

```
NameError in 'MembershipsController should allow you to save updates to the notes'
undefined local variable or method `activate_authlogic' for #<Spec::Rails::Example::ControllerExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0x107cee930>
```

I don't understand why `activate_authlogic` is undefined in this case. I've used this line in TestUnit many times, and the RSpec examples I've read all seem to say that this should work. **NOTE:** I've also tried adding `require 'authlogic'` to the top of the `_spec` file, but it produces an identical error message.

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')
require 'ruby-debug'

describe MembershipsController do

  before(:each) do
    activate_authlogic
    @admin = Factory(:admin, :email => "admin@example.com")
    UserSession.create(@admin)
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a misunderstanding on my part. Instead of `require 'authlogic'`

I needed `require 'authlogic/test_case'`

Comment: Thanks [@Shevaun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/156109/shevaun) for the typo correction